# Copying too big table from a database to another via mysqldump silently drops rows

Tags: mysql

I have this command:

```
mysqldump -uUSER1 -pPASS1 --single-transaction --quick --hex-blob --triggers database1 table | mysql -uUSER2 -pPASS2 database2
```

The table (which is the `post` table from a forum's database) has around 1.5M rows and has been growing over the years.

This has always worked, until recently. Now, all rows exceeding a certain number are systematically lost. The strangest thing is that this happens silently without any error message.

Another strange thing is that when transferring the exact same table from the exact same database to a different database on another server, i.e.

```
mysqldump -uUSER1 -pPASS1 --single-transaction --quick --hex-blob --triggers database1 table | mysql -hHOST2 -uUSER2 -pPASS2 database2
```

this still works!

There's no disk space issue on the server or anything like that. I have tried manually inserting new rows to the same table and there are no issues.

I'm guessing there might be some sort of buffering or memory issue related to piping the whole output from a mysqldump into a mysql command in one pipe or something?

Is there a simple solution, perhaps by tweaking some parameters of mysqldump or mysql, that doesn't involve too complicate stuff such as breaking the transfer into chunks of N rows? (or even a simple way to do that)?

Comment: Ald the size of the dump file is approximately 2GB ?

Comment: there's no actual file, since the output of mysqldump is being piped to the input of mysql

Comment: anyway I've just tried dumping the whole table to an actual file and it's less than 1.5GB